# Same acronym for two words

Tags: acronyms

I would like to use the same acronym (SC} either for the word "superconductivity" or for the word "superconductor". Of course I want my acronym list to explain it in a single line by something like:

> **SC**    superconductivity/superconductor

To produce acronyms I used the package acronym, so that in the text I write: 
`\ac{ABC}`, where `\ac{ABC}` is defined in the environment `acronym`:

```
\begin{acronym}
.....
....
\acro{ABC}{AlexBarbaraCat}
....
...
\end{acronym}
```

Can I achieve it? How?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please give us some small code which shows how you are producing your acronyms list. Like this, it would just be a guessing around.

Answer (score 3):

The following may be sufficient for you: provide one definition in the list, with the extra use supplied by `\acroextra`, and place a non-listed definition at the top of your document via `\acrodef`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}
\acrodef{SC2}[SC]{superconductor}

\ac{SC1} is a property of \acp{SC2}.

\begin{acronym}
\acro{SC1}[SC]{superconductivity\acroextra{/superconductor}}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```