# Same acronyms for different words with acro package

Tags: acronyms, acro

I have different words with same acronym (FE finite element/ferroelectric).
I've found two similar discussions, though none of them were using `acro` package.
I was wondering is it possible to do it with `acro`?
Thanks!

[Acronyms for same abbreviations with different meaning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458778/acronyms-for-same-abbreviations-with-different-meaning)

[Same acronym for two words](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208058/same-acronym-for-two-words)

Comment: @wayne can you please explain what you mean by “do it” mean? Two acronyms can easily have the same short form if that's what you mean.

Comment: It gives error if I \DeclareAcronym{A} for both "a" and "aa".

Comment: @wayne I'm sorry, without an @mention I'm not notitified about your comment. I still don't understand what you want: you can do `\DeclareAcronym{xx}{ short = xx , long = bla}` and `\DeclareAcronym{yy}{ short = xx , long = blub}`. Can't you give a real world example about what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi, what you suggest gives two item in the list:
- xx   bla,  xx   blub.
Though what I want is one item in the list as: xx   bla/blub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can define two acronyms with a common short form, and then exclude one from the list and redefine how the other appears to essentially merge them in the list entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{xx}{
    short = xx,
    long = blah,
    list = blah/blub,
}
\DeclareAcronym{yy}{
    short = xx,
    long = blub,
    tag = dupe,
}

\begin{document}

Foo \ac{xx} bar \ac{yy}
bat \ac{xx} baz \ac{yy}

\printacronyms[exclude={dupe}]
\end{document}
```

This is essentially an abuse of design and probably for good reason as the two acronyms share a short form making the short form ambiguous (it's possible if the acronyms share a short-form due to a close similarity then this is an xy question and can be better implemented in [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) in a more intended manner).
As such the two definitions are closely interconnected and a change to one may require an update to the other.

Unintended consequences may also happen if trying to use the `single` key, although they could in principle be accounted for using the likes of `\acuse` and `\acroifused`.